# Querying to find if some columns are in array

Tags: mysql

I have a complex nested-query which is inside a join, is it possible to find several columns that match that query instead of repeating the query in the Join? ie:

```
select * from 
A left join B on a.xid=b.xid and 
(a.userid or b.userid) in (select userid from A where..)
```

^^^  don't want to duplicate the nested-query...

There is a nested query that should match several columns from the parent-query (as seen in the example above). The simple way is to duplicate the nested query several times. ie-

```
select * from A
left join B
  on a.xid=b.xid
  and a.userid in (select userid from ...)
  and b.userid in (Select userid from ....)
```

BUT - since the subquery is bit complicated I don't want mysql to run it twice, but rather only once and than match it against several of the parent query columns.

Comment: more specific?
There is a nested query that should match several columns from the parent-query (as seen in the example above). The simple way is to duplicate the nested query several times. ie-
`select * from A left join B on a.xid=b.xid and a.userid in (select userid from ...) AND b.userid in (Select userid from ....)`
BUT - since the subquery is bit complicated I don't want mysql to run it twice, but rather only once and than match it against several of the parent query columns.

Comment: There may be a way, but we'll need to see the whole query to determine. With what you've provided so far, no, there's no way to avoid doubling the subquery. Please update your question then let us know it's updated by commenting here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your subquery is working properly and you have the query cache turned on you won't have to worry about performance. If its a question of it being overly complex then maybe you could use a proc for this query: put the results of the sub into a temp table and join to it.

There are lots of ways to approach this.

Comment: Thanks, that's just what I realized yesterday (the temp table)